# ImageMagick "convert" utility Magick++ equivalent?

Tags: c++, image-processing, svg, imagemagick, magick++

Sorry if the title didn't make any sense.

Currently, the following parameters on the imagemagick convert utility are perfect for what I need. I'm tring to take an .svg file, make it larger and write it as a png file.

```
 convert -density 36  home.svg  home_1.png
```

Unfortunately, I need to be using Magick++ (the C++ Interface/API for ImageMagick), but I can't seem to get the equivalent operation in Magick++.

Are there any ImageMagick pros that would be able to help me out on this?

My current code is:

```
image.density(Geometry(36,36));

    image.read( "Character.svg" );

    image.write( "xx.png" );
```

I've tried moving the `image.density()` part around, but my image is never changes. It's simply rasterized and saved as a png.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm no ImageMagick pro, but when I tried this code:

```
#include <Magick++.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  Magick::Image img;
  img.density(Magick::Geometry(36,36));
  img.read(argv[1]);
  img.write(argv[2]);

  img.density(Magick::Geometry(72,72));
  img.read(argv[1]);
  img.write(argv[3]);
}
```

with [this SVG file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File%3aExample.svg), e.g.:

```
$ ./resize example.svg out_small.png out_large.png
```

...the file `out_small.png` was 300x300 pixels, whereas `out_large.png` was 600x600 pixels.

This was on Windows 7 via cygwin.

Comment: Wow that's interesting. When I try almost the same code on environment, it doesn't work. Using the same SVG example you used, both mine output to 600x600 pixels. I'm using MSVC, so maybe it's bugged?

Comment: Sure, it's possible MSVC has some issues with this.  I'd be curious if this works for you with other input/output file formats, or if any of the image modifiers work.

Comment: I've tried some other modifiers like zoom() and it seems to work so I think MSVC is just having issues with the SVG/density stuff.