# Export vtkChartXY/vtkPlot as a high resolution raster image (JPG or PNG)

Tags: c++, image, qt, vtk, rasterizing

I want to export a 2D chart (`vtkChartXY`) as a high resolution bitmap image (`JPG` or `PNG`). I'm able to export an image at screen resolution:

[image]

But when I try to increase the resolution using `vtkWindowToImageFilter::SetMagnification(10)`, I obtain the following distorted image:

[image]

The text is just fine, but there are undesired spacings between the line segments.

I used the following code to generate the graph:

```
// Construct a random 2D chart
vtkNew<vtkContextView> pView;
vtkNew<vtkChartXY> pChart;
vtkPlot *pPlot = pChart->AddPlot(vtkChart::LINE);
vtkNew<vtkTable> pTable;
vtkNew<vtkDoubleArray> pX, pY;
pX->SetName("x");
pY->SetName("y");
for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
{
  pX->InsertNextTuple1(i);
  pY->InsertNextTuple1(std::rand());
}
pTable->AddColumn(pX.Get());
pTable->AddColumn(pY.Get());
pPlot->SetInputData(pTable.Get(), "x", "y");
pView->GetScene()->AddItem(pChart.Get());
```

And the following code to export the graph to `JPEG`:

```
// Export the image to JPG
vtkNew<vtkRenderWindow> renderWindow;
renderWindow->AddRenderer(pView->GetRenderer());
renderWindow->SetSize(300, 300);
renderWindow->OffScreenRenderingOn();
renderWindow->Render();

vtkNew<vtkWindowToImageFilter> windowToImageFilter;
windowToImageFilter->SetInput(renderWindow.Get());
// windowToImageFilter->SetMagnification(10); // uncomment this line to obtain the distorted image

vtkNew<vtkJPEGWriter> writer;
writer->SetFileName("test.jpg");
writer->SetInputConnection(windowToImageFilter->GetOutputPort());
writer->Write();
```

If it matters, I'm using VTK 7.1 on Ubuntu 16.04.

**Question:** How can I export a `vtkChartXY` as a high resolution image without distorting my graph, i.e. undesired spacings between the line segments?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*This is not a clean solution, but rather a trick to overcome the problem.*

The trick is to firstly export the chart to SVG and secondly use a third party library to convert it to the desired high resolution bitmap image.

1. Exporting SVG image

   ```
   vtkNew<vtkGL2PSExporter> exp;
   exp->SetRenderWindow(renderWindow.Get());
   exp->SetFileFormatToSVG();
   exp->SetFilePrefix("test");
   exp->Write();
   ```
2. Convert SVG to high resolution bitmap image (ex. png)

   Multiple libraries are able to perform this conversion, for example:

   - [Inkscape](https://inkscape.org/): one can use the following command line method to convert the SVG file to a 300dpi png file:

     ```
     inkscape test.svg -e test.png -d 300
     ```

     Which may be executed from C++ in a cross-platform way using [Qt](https://www.qt.io/)'s [`QProcess`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html) class:

     ```
     QProcess p;
     p.startDetached("inkscape test.svg -e test.png -d 300");
     ```
   - [Qt](https://www.qt.io/)'s [`QSvgRenderer`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsvgrenderer.html)

     ```
     QSvgRenderer renderer (QLatin1String("test.svg"));
     const QSize imageSize(4*renderer.defaultSize()); // four times screen resolution
     QImage image(imageSize, QImage::Format_ARGB32);
     image.fill(Qt::transparent);
     QPainter painter;
     painter.begin(&image);
     renderer.render(&painter, QRectF(QPointF(), QSizeF(imageSize)));
     painter.end();
     image.save("test.png");
     ```

     Note that this implementation may [lack support for some important attributes such as `baseline-shift` and `dy`](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-61677). Therefore, better results may be obtained by converting text to paths while exporting to SVG as follows:

     ```
     exp->TextAsPathOn();
     ```
   - [Magick++](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/magick++.php) (C++ API of [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/)): See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4180916/imagemagick-convert-utility-magick-equivalent) for more information.